# How to open PPT 2016 in reading view automatically ？

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm developing a software that can automatically open Microsoft PPT 2016 in reading view.Could I pass certain parameter to ppt process or call vba script to develop this function ? Or , is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Later find a correct answer from:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/PowerPoint/ppShowTypeWindow.htm

```
Sub show()
  With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings
    .LoopUntilStopped = msoCTrue
    .AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings
    .ShowType = ppShowTypeWindow
    .Run
   End With
End Sub
```