Automatically open a PowerPoint file in Reading view
I created a macro in PowerPoint that has an error in the middle of it that prevents it from opening in reading view mode.
Sub OpenPowerPointInReadingView()

    Dim pptApp As Object

    Dim pptPresentation As Object



    

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

   

Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Caminho\Para\Sua\Apresentacao.pptx")

    pptPresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View = 3 ' ppViewSpeakerNotes

    

pptApp.Visible = True

End Sub


"has an error" - what specific error though, and on which line of code?

ppViewSpeakerNotes isn't an actual PowerPoint VBA constant?

Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994473/how-to-open-ppt-2016-in-reading-view-automatically

@TimWilliams is correct. ppViewSpeakerNotes doesn't exist. Also, this looks like ChatGPT code, which always writes code for PowerPoint as though you're automating it from some other app. If you're running this from within PPT, nearly all of the code you have here is unnecessary.

@Steve Rindsberg. I actually consulted chatGPT. Because of this I am having this error. Can you help me overcome it?

Please see the Stack Overflow policy banning ChatGPT code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

ChatGPT can give you hints; some of its hints help, some send  you off a cliff.  As @JohnKorchok's pointed out, ChatGPT code isn't welcome here.

There's no constant for reading view so you have to sort of tell PPT to push its own buttons. I've deleted all of the ChatGPTjunk, added one line to push the right button, giving us this:
Sub OpenPowerPointInReadingView()

Presentations.Open("C:\Caminho\Para\Sua\Apresentacao.pptx")
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ViewSlideShowReadingView")

End Sub

